# A question regarding functions of functions and continuous functions

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I define the relation "$g$ is a function of $f$", iff there exists a function $h$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $h$ composed with $f$ equals $g$. I also define the relation "$g$ is a continuous function of $f$", iff there exists a continuous real function $h$ such that $h$ composed with $f$ equals $g$. Now, my question is, does there exist two continuous function $f$ and $g$, such that $g$ is a function of $f$, but $g$ is not a continuous function of $f$?

Comment: Sure. Since many continuous functions don't have a continuous inverse, you can just take $f$ to be such a function and $g$ the identity $g(x)=x$.

Comment: @aschepler But, does there exist a continuous real function which has an inverse which is not continuous?

Comment: A continuous function on $\Bbb R$ is invertible if and only if it is strictly monotone (increasing or decreasing). The inverse of a monotone function is also monotone. Monotone functions can only have jump discontinuities. So if $f^{-1}$ exists but is not continuous, then $f$ itself must not be defined on the interval skipped by the jump in $f^{-1}$. This is precluded by the assumption that $f$ is defined on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: But while the direct application aschepler gives to your situation is voided by a technicality, you should still give serious consideration to how the concept can be adapted.